# @react-navigation/native-stack could not be found within the project or these directories:

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I actually have the react-navigation/native-stack module in my project files but still, I am receiving this module missing error.someone please help.

Here is my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
},

"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.65.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.7.2"
},

"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
},
```

[here is the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCeS5.png)

Comment: Have you tried all the steps that mentioned in the error? such as, `watchmen watch delete...`